# dropdownlistfor wrong type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I got this error message when I tried to run my system.

> "The ViewData item that has the key 'question' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'"

How can I fix this?

Controller

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems(IEnumerable<string> elements)
{
    // Create an empty list to hold result of the operation
    var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    // For each string in the 'elements' variable, create a new SelectListItem object
    // that has both its Value and Text properties set to a particular value.
    // This will result in MVC rendering each item as:
    //     <option value="State Name">State Name</option>
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        selectList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = element,
            Text = element
        });
    }

    return selectList;
}
private IEnumerable<string> GetAllQuestions()
{
    return new List<string>
    {
        "In which city were you born?",
        ...
    };
}
```

Model

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Question:")]
public string question { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> questions { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.question)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.question, Model.questions, "- Please select a security question -", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Comment: `(m => Model.question` should be `(m => m.question`

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic given that a simple .NET Fiddle was unable to reproduce the issue with the posted code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/snFopi Please read [ask] and post a [mcve]